# PHP app not responding in cloud server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache2

I wrote a php app. The app working fine on my localhost. But not responding on server.

I have installed ubuntu 14.4 with apache2, mysql 5.5 and php5 on my local machine. I setup the server as same as the local machine. Same ubuntu, apache, mysql and php.

I used PDO for handling mysql connections. Apps's login and some insert, update pages are working. All pages which is listing data are working fine. But in both pages app stucks with loading with running some mysql insert and update queries.

Why was that?

Comment: are you getting any errors? remember to set display_errors to true in the php.ini file

Comment: check in `/var/log/apache2` folder for error log

Comment: Also check php global error_log file if it's not set , configure it from php.ini restart your apache service try again to run your app and finaly check that error_log file provide us that log

Comment: Ram was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ram was the problem..i upgrade ram to 8gb..now its working fine..previous ram was 1gb..